# Clojure get nested map value

Tags: clojure

So I'm used to having a nested array or map of settings in my applications. I tried setting one up in Clojure like this:

```
(def gridSettings
  {:width 50
   :height 50
   :ground {:variations 25}
   :water {:variations 25}
   })
```

And I wondered if you know of a good way of retrieving a nested value? I tried writing

```
(:variations (:ground gridSettings))
```

Which works, but it's backwords and rather cumbersome, especially if I add a few levels.

Comment: Both mtaka's and dbyrne's answers are common ways to solve this issue. Use whichever strikes your fancy! I would note that get-in makes your intent clearer.

Comment: I think it's time to accept one of these answers. My heart says *dbyrne* but my head says *mtyaka* :)

Comment: @joelittlejohn Hard to choose an answer because they're all right and useful and I think people are best served by reading them all!

Answer (score 40):

That's what `get-in` does:

```
(get-in gridSettings [:ground :variations])
```

From the docstring:

> ```
> clojure.core/get-in
> ([m ks] [m ks not-found])
>   Returns the value in a nested associative structure,
>   where ks is a sequence of keys. Returns nil if the key
>   is not present, or the not-found value if supplied.
> ```

Answer (score 31):

You can use the [thread-first macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E):

```
(-> gridSettings :ground :variations)
```

I prefer `->` over `get-in` except for two special cases:

- When the keys are an arbitrary sequence determined at runtime.
- When supplying a not-found value is useful.

Comment: what will be the result if `(:ground gridSettings)` is nil?

Comment: The result of the whole expression will just be `nil`.  There won't be an exception thrown.

Comment: `(:ground nil) ;=> nil`. Using `->` unless you deliberately need something else also seems to be idiomatic Clojure.

Comment: But `->` can be used with `or` to also nicely return a not-found value. `(get-in grid-settings [:ground :variations] "not found!")` vs.
`(-> grid-settings :ground :variations (or "not found!"))`

Comment: You can also use -> when you need predicates that aren't keywords, i.e. when finding the next step on the navigation path requires calling a function.

Answer (score 14):

Apart from what other answers has mentioned (`get-in` and `->` macro), sometimes you want to fetch multiple values from a map (nested or not), in those cases de-structuring can be really helpful

```
(let [{{gv :variations} :ground
       {wv :variations} :water} gridSettings]
  [gv wv])
```

Answer (score 3):

Maps are partial functions (as in not total). Thus, one can simply apply them as functions. Based on the map from the question:

```
(gridSettings :ground)
;=> {:variations 25}
```

The result is a map. So, it can be applied again, which results in a very similar (but not backwards) "syntax" as proposed in the question:

```
((gridSettings :ground) :variations)
;=>25
```